# What does this mean by site IP or Fully Qualified Domain Name?

Tags: command-line, virtualhost

I'm configuring a virtual host and the instruction is as follows:

> edit the new example.com.conf configuration file by uncommenting
>   ServerName and replacing example.com with your site's IP or Fully
>   Qualified Domain Name(FQDN).

Do I just add the domain name I intend on using for the site or is it something else?
This may be a silly question but I don't wanna bug this out. Cheers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name . Not a silly question for regular users. However, for someone configuring virtual hosts is actually worse than that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's apache you are configureing?

Example:
You have the domain: mycleverdomainname.com

Configure the DNS for mycleverdomainname.com with an A-record pointing to your webbserver IP-adress.

Your apache virtualhost can look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mycleverdomainname.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myclever/

 <Directory /var/www/myclever/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
 </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```